# How to Replace String having Substring of Unlimited Characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace a string

```
var url = "www.fnord.com/foo/bar/btn_close_white.gif";
```

Simple word for word for word replacement works fine:

```
var newUrl = url.replace(/btn_close_white.gif/g,"btn_close_black.gif");
```

Yet since I do not know what color is currently set, I need the regex to ignore the color part and replace the whole segment. So that in theory, `btn_close_pink.gif` or `btn_close_someOtherFancyColor.gif` all get replaced to `btn_close_black.gif`.

I tried this, but it fails and I do not know why:

```
var newUrl = url.replace(/btn_close_*.gif/g,"btn_close_black.gif"); // this fails
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = "www.fnord.com/foo/bar/btn_close_white.gif";
var newUrl = url.replace(/btn_close_[\w\d]*\.gif/g,"btn_close_black.gif");
```

Regexp `[\w\d]*` means any amount of letters or digits. If you allow any characters in url do this:

```
var newUrl = url.replace(/btn_close_.*\.gif/g,"btn_close_black.gif");
```

EDIT: When your write `"/btn_close_*\.gif/"` regexp this means that your string should contain "btn_close" string + any amount of "_" character + ".gif" string.

When your write `"/btn_close_.*\.gif/"` regexp this means that your string should contain "btn_close" string + any amount of any characters + ".gif" string.

Comment: This gets the job done. Could you please explain why you did it the way you did? I understand that I forgot to escape the dot at the gif part. But why did you have to `.*`? Why was the `*` not sufficent on its own?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using rather cumbersome replace operation, when you could simply concatenate strings? If not, I suggest this:

```
var url = "www.fnord.com/foo/bar/btn_close_white.gif";
var newUrl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1,-1)+"btn_close_black.gif"
```

all it does is finding the last slash an removing all following characters, so you can easily append your filename.

Comment: In fact, there is. I did not include the fact that the string in question is part of a much larger string.